# how to stop xcode user interface from highlighting blocks of code

Tags: xcode, user-interface, settings

I cannot for the life of me figure out how to get rid of this UI setting on xcode where it highlights blocks of code.. internet researching has been unhelpful.. anyone?[see picture here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/duQpg.png)

Comment: Did you select these code or it always be highlighted ?

Comment: wherever I click my cursor it highlights that block of code

Comment: Did you tap `Shift` key when you click cursor ?

Comment: no. its a UI setting of some sort. I am not highlighting the text

Answer (score 1):

found it. editor >> code folding >> focus follows section